# How will Oracle optimise a record set if we specify a rownum clause

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

If I say:

```
select * from table order by col1 where rownum < 100
```

If the table has 10 million records, will Oracle bring all 10 million, sort it and then show me the first 10? Or is there a way it will optimise it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this

```
select * from table order by col1 where rownum < 100
```

then Oracle will throw an error as the WHERE clause comes before the ORDER BY.

If you do this

```
select * from table where rownum < 100 order by col1
```

then Oracle will return a random 99 records as the WHERE clause comes before the ORDER BY.

If you want to return a the first 100 records, ordered by a column, you *must* put the order by in a sub-select.

```
select * 
  from ( select * from table order by col1 )
 where rownum <= 100
```

Oracle will do the sort, how else will it know the records you want? However, it will be a sort with a stopkey because of the ROWNUM. Oracle doesn't *actually* sort the entire result set, as some optimisation goes on under the hood, but this is what you can assume takes place.

Please see [this article by Tom Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html).

Comment: New with Oracle 12c -- LIMIT and OFFSET clauses.

Comment: Hmmm, yes that is going to get some getting used to @David... People are going to have to tag with version! I suspect it'll do the same thing though... just disguise it slightly.

Comment: They've gone for the newest version of the ANSI standard so it's nice and flexible and confusing -- http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php