# Oracle select one row in join and subquery inside a decode function

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, decode, oracle9i

I have two Oracle(9i) tables (EVENTS and EVENTS_ELEMENTS). The TABLE EVENTS has a PK (ID) associated to ID_EVENTO as FK (EVENTS_ELEMENTS).

```
Table EVENTS
    ----------------------------------
    | ID | TIPO | FECHAINICIO        |
    ----------------------------------
    | 23 | real | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss|
    | 97 | real | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss|
    ----------------------------------

Table EVENTS_ELEMENTs
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | ID_EVENTO | FIN_PREVISTO        | FIN_REAL           | PORCENTAJE | ID_ELEMENTO |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | 23        | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss |dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss | 100        | 731         |
    | 23        | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss |dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss | 100        | 732         |
    | 23        | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss |dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss | 73         | 733         |
    | 97        | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss |dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss | 100        | 840         |
    | 97        | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss |dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss | 100        | 841         |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in my query i want to export the number of events completed or incomplete (depending the value PORCENTAJE in EVENTS_ELEMENTS).

First I used this Query to obtain the last row of every EVENT:

```
SELECT *
FROM EVENTS eve, EVENTS_ELEMENTS el
WHERE eve.ID(+) = el.ID_EVENTO and ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY ID desc
```

trying to obtain this result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | TIPO | FECHAINICIO        |  ID_EVENTO | FIN_PREVISTO        | FIN_REAL           | PORCENTAJE | ID_ELEMENTO |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 23 | real | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss|  23        | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss |dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss | 73         | 733         |
| 97 | real | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss|  97        | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss |dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss | 100        | 841         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but my result is only one row with EVENT, not every EVENT with the last EVENTS_ELEMENTS row with the PORCENTAJE value what i need to calculate what EVENTS are completed and what are un execution.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | TIPO | FECHAINICIO        |  ID_EVENTO | FIN_PREVISTO        | FIN_REAL           | PORCENTAJE | ID_ELEMENTO |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 23 | real | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss|  23        | dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss |dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss | 73         | 733         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After this, i want to count the number of completed and no-completed. Im trying to understand the DECODE function. In this example i try to get the result:

```
---------------------------------
| LABEL    | SERIE      | VALUE |
---------------------------------
| COMPLETO | Serie-Text | 1     |
| EJECUCION| Serie-Text | 1     |
---------------------------------
if PORCENTAJE == 100 -> COMPLETO
if PORCENTAJE != 100 -> EJECUCION
```

I suppose the second Query should be:

```
SELECT DECODE (EVENTS,
                  (SELECT count(*)
               FROM [Query of first question]), 'COMPLETO',
              (SELECT count(*)
               FROM [Similar Query of first question]), 'EJECUCION') as LABEL,
    'Serie-Text' as SERIE,
    count(ev.ID) as VALUE
FROM EVENTS ev, EVENTS_ELEMENTS el
WHERE ev.ID(+) = el.ID_EVENTO
```

Comment: You only get one result because of `rownum = 1`. [ROWNUM is a psuedocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) that operates on the result-set, not on the group/partition. This leaves you with one row. It's worth noting that the last evaluated part of a SELECT statement is the ORDER BY. This means that your condition on ROWNUM is [evaluated _before_ your ORDER BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476998/how-will-oracle-optimise-a-record-set-if-we-specify-a-rownum-clause/17477257#17477257), leaving you with a random row.

Comment: Next, it's really not that clear what you're asking for here. Your first result, are you looking for the minimum start date and the maximum end date? What logic determines the rows you return. Your second statement is even more confusing. Why is only one completed? Based on your own logic they both seem to be? It's also not clear where you get the value of 1 from, shouldn't it be 3 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query fits your needs:

```
select ev.ID, ev.TIPO, evFECHAINICIO,
       decode(ev.PORCENTAJE, 100, 'COMPLETED', 'IN PROGRESS') status, count(*) nb
from EVENTS_ELEMENTS el, EVENTS ev
where ev.ID = el.ID_EVENTO
group by ev.ID, ev.TIPO, evFECHAINICIO,
      decode(ev.PORCENTAJE, 100, 'COMPLETED', 'IN PROGRESS')
;
```

I group by ID and status, status being computed thanks to the `decode` function: if percentage is 100, status is completed, else it is in progress.

Comment: Thanks, i modified the query (a little) and now it works perfectly. `select ev.TIPO SERIE, 
       decode(el.PORCENTAJE, 100, 'COMPLETED', 'IN PROGRESS') LABEL, count(*) VALUE
from EVENTO_ELEMENTO el, EVENTOS ev
where ev.ID = el.ID_EVENTO
      and ev.TIPO = 'simulacion'
group by  ev.TIPO, ev.FECHAINICIO,
      decode(el.PORCENTAJE, 100, 'COMPLETED', 'IN PROGRESS')` 

and now my table is like i said before:
LABEL = COMPLETED / IN PROGRESS (depending of PORCENTAJE value)
SERIE = ev.TIPO
VALUE = count of completed / in progress

Seriously, Thank you, i was blocked for a week.